# fancybox encoding issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, hebrew

i am using fancybox.net for my light boxes. it works great with images. but when i use iframe option i am having problems with encoding.

i use hebrew and english and russian on my website. when i use UTF-8 on the iframe page i get squares instead of hebrew letters.

when i change to iso-8859-8 i have hebrew but inverted, and russian goes: ???????????

any idea? my website is UTF-8 and every thing works great.. except fancybox :(